# Crosscompile Qt4.8.5 for x86_64-linux, disable xlib-config.test

Tags: c++, qt, cross-compiling

I want to compile Qt 4.8.5 for a X86_64 machine running linux 2.6.32 with an glibc 2.12.1 on my LinuxMint 14 machine. I created an appropriate crosscompiler using crosstool-ng and installed it via this mkspec (named linux-cluster)

```
MAKEFILE_GENERATOR      = UNIX
TARGET_PLATFORM         = unix
TEMPLATE                = app
CONFIG                  += qt warn_on release incremental link_prl gdb_dwarf_index
QT                      += core gui
QMAKE_INCREMENTAL_STYLE = sublib

include(../common/linux.conf)
include(../common/gcc-base-unix.conf)
include(../common/g++-unix.conf)

# modifications to g++.conf
QMAKE_CC = x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc
QMAKE_CXX = x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-g++
QMAKE_LINK = x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-g++
QMAKE_LINK_SHLIB = x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-g++ 

# modifications to linux.conf
QMAKE_AR = x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-ar cqs
QMAKE_OBJCOPY = x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-objcopy
QMAKE_STRIP = x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-strip

# Hack to get the config.test to compile at least
QMAKE_INCDIR_X11 = /usr/include/
QMAKE_LIBDIR_X11 = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/

load(qt_config)
```

My configure call then is:

```
../qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.5/configure -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=/<home>/x-tools/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu- -platform linux-cluster -xplatform linux-cluster -opensource -verbose -prefix /<home>/qt48-install -continue -no-webkit
```

Qt seems to configure fine using the x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-g++ compiler, however then it performs some config.test, e.g. it compiles a test Xlib-application which fails:

```
x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W  -I../../../../qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.5/mkspecs/linux-cluster -I../../../../qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.5/config.tests/x11/xlib -I/usr/include -I../../../../qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.5/config.tests/x11/xlib -I. -o xlib.o ../../../../qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.5/config.tests/x11/xlib/xlib.cpp
x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-g++ -Wl,-O1 -o xlib xlib.o    -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/  -lXext -lX11 -lm
/<home>/x-tools/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.3.6/../../../../x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ld: warning: libxcb.so.1, needed by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu//libX11.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
```

it does so, of course, because there is no libxext in the crosscompiler.

My question is: I'm cross-compiling here, why does qt perform tests if a host(!) is able to compile a X11 application when the result of the qt-build is destined to run on an entirely different platform? How can I disable (certain) of these config-tests?

(I managed to circumvent the xlib-test by adding -embedded X86 to my configure call, after which qt compiles just fine. However as I also need -opengl desktop this is not an option since they seem to be mutual exclusive options)

Comment: if your goal is just crosscompiling itself, you "just" need to have the appropriate qmake-spec. Then `qmake -> make` as the usual install. [this link](http://silmor.de/qtstuff.cross.php) is quite old, but I used it as a starting point.

Comment: Not really an answer, but you might want to check how they do it on Arch Linux https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/mingw-w64-qt4/